# DAX PowerBI filter against another Table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables: `Sales` and `VIPS`. The sales table will include customers who are not in the VIP Customer table.

I want to create a Measure to find a distinct count of VIP Customers in the Sales table who have bought a sale and a non-sale product.

I’ve been trying to filter the Sales Table on the VIP Customer table, to get sales only relating to VIPs and then Distinct Counting those but I’ve had no success.

```
VIPSales =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( Sales[USERID] ),
    Sales[SaleItem] = 1 || Sales[SaleItem] = 0,
    CROSSFILTER ( Sales[UserID], VIPS[UserID], ONEWAY_LEFTFILTERSRIGHT )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about counting which VIPs have two distinct `SalesItem` values?

```
VIPSales =
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        VALUES ( VIPS[UserID] ),
        CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( Sales[SaleItem] ) ) = 2
    )
)
```

This assumes there is a one-to-many relationship where `VIPS` filters `Sales`. If not, then you'll need an extra argument for CALCULATE to do the filtering.